# Pattern matching against generic type using 'flexible' type parameter

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

```
match value with
| :? list<#SomeType> as l -> l //Is it possible to match any list of a type derived from SomeType?
| _ -> failwith "doesn't match"
```

Comment: Not that I suppose it matters but why do you need to match with a list of some type?  If the list is homogenous then you can simply process the list element by element and that's fine.  If the list is heterogenous then you can't consider the list as a logical unit anyway.  What's the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I suppose I should have used my actual code. I'm just using list<T> for simplicity. The question is how to do a flexible match on type parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's unfortunately not possible to do something like this - the CLR doesn't provide any efficient way of doing that kind of type test.  See [How to cast an object to a list of generic type in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140079/how-to-cast-an-object-to-a-list-of-generic-type-in-f) and [F# and pattern matching on generics in a non-generic method implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174042/f-and-pattern-matching-on-generics-in-a-non-generic-method-implementing-an-inter) for a few (rather ugly) solutions.

Answer (score 9):

As already pointed out, there is no way to do this directly (pattern matching can only bind values, but it cannot bind new type variables). In addition to the (more general) workaround by *kvb* you can use the fact that all collections implement non-generic `IEnumerable`, so you can check for this type:

```
match box value with 
| :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as l when 
     // assumes that the actual type of 'l' is 'List<T>' or some other type
     // with single generic type parameter (this is not fully correct, because
     // it could be other type too, but we can ignore this for now)
     typedefof<SomeType>.IsAssignableFrom
       (value.GetType().GetGenericArguments().[0]) -> 
   l |> Seq.cast<SomeType>
| _ -> failwith "doesn't match"
```

The code tests whether the value is a non-generic `IEnumerable` and whether the type parameter is subtype of `SomeType`. In that case, we got a list of some derived type, so we can cast it to a sequence of `SomeType` values (this is slightly different than working with list of values of the derived types, but it shouldn't matter for practical purposes).

Answer (score 2):

I later needed something similar for matching Lazy instances. Here's my solution, in case anyone finds it helpful.

```
let (|Lazy|_|) (value : obj) =
    if box value <> null then
        let typ = value.GetType()
        if typ.IsGenericType && typ.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Lazy<_>> then
            Some(typ.GetGenericArguments().[0])
        else None
    else None
```

Usage:

```
match value with
| Lazy typ when typeof<SomeType>.IsAssignableFrom(typ) -> (value :?> Lazy<_>).Value
| _ -> failwith "not an instance of Lazy<#SomeType>"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [F# 2.0 specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html), par. 14.5.2 (Solving Subtype Constraints), it will not work, because: "F# generic types do not support covariance or contravariance."

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest, but effective:

```
let matchType<'T> () =
    try
        let o = Activator.CreateInstance<'T> ()
        match box o with
        | :? Type1 -> printfn "Type1"
        | :? Type2 -> printfn "Type2"
        | _ -> failwith "unknown type"
    with
    | ex -> failwith "%s" (ex.ToString())
```