# F# Pattern Matching: Matching functions/lists of subtypes?

Tags: f#

```
let f (O: obj) = 
    match O with
        | :? (obj -> list<obj>) -> "win"
        | :? list<obj> -> "list!"
        | _ -> "fail"

Console.WriteLine(f(fun x -> ["lol"]))
Console.WriteLine(f(["lol"]))
```

prints "fail" twice, as I suppose it should, because I am giving i a function `obj -> list<String>`, which is not a `obj -> list<obj>`. Is there any way to make them match though? I could upcast each list into a `list<obj>` before making an anonymous function out of it, or I could upcast everything to `obj` before putting it into the list.

Either of those works and makes it match, but i thought this was the problem that covariance/contravariance was meant to have already solved? Correct me if i'm mistaken

Comment: F# doesn't support co/contravariance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't solve this using any built-in pattern matching.

The only way to find out whether an `obj` value is some F# function is to use F# Reflection and call the `FSharpType.IsFunction` method on the type. You can check for the case in your example like this:

```
open System    
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection    

let f (o : obj) =  
  let ty = o.GetType() 
  if FSharpType.IsFunction(ty) then
    let tyFrom, tyTo = FSharpType.GetFunctionElements(ty)
    if tyTo.IsGenericType && tyTo.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<list<_>> then
      printfn "win"
    else 
      printfn "wrong function"
  else
    printfn "not a function"

Console.WriteLine(f(fun x -> "lol"))    // wrong function
Console.WriteLine(f(fun x -> ["lol"]))  // win
Console.WriteLine(f(["lol"]))           // not a function
```

You could encapsulate the behavior in an F# active pattern to make the syntax a bit nicer (and use pattern matching on types). However, another problem is that this doesn't give you a function that you could use to actually invoke the function dynamically. I don't think there is a built-in library function for this, so you'll probably need to use .NET reflection to call the `Invoke` method dynamically.

**EDIT**: There has been similar related questions on SO. The general problem is that you're matching against some (any) instantiation of a specific generic type, so the same issue arises with lists etc. See for example:

- [F# and pattern matching on generics...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174042/f-and-pattern-matching-on-generics-in-a-non-generic-method-implementing-an-inte)
- [Pattern matching against generic type...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764867/pattern-matching-against-generic-type-using-flexible-type-parameter)
- [How to cast an object to a list...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140079/how-to-cast-an-object-to-a-list-of-generic-type-in-f)