# How to convert a list of objects to a primitive data type?

Tags: list, f#

I have this dicriminated union that represents a primitive type:

```
type Expr = 
    | Int of bigint
    | Real of float
    | Symbol of string
    | Bool of bool
    | List of Expr list
```

And I am writing a function `list : obj list -> Expr list` that will check for the types of objects and converts them to `Expr`'s accordingly:

```
let rec list : (obj list -> Expr list) = function
    | head::tail -> 
        match head with
        | :? string as x'-> Symbol (x') :: list tail
        | :? int as x'-> Int(bigint x') :: list tail
        | :? bigint as x' -> Int x' :: list tail
        | :? bool as x' -> Bool x' :: list tail
        | :? float as x' -> Real x' :: list tail
        | :? Expr as x' -> x' :: list tail
        | :? list<obj> as x' -> List(list x') :: list tail
    | _ -> []
```

The case `| :? list<obj> as x' -> List(list x') :: list tail` doesn't seem to match when calling this function on a nested list like this: `list [1;[2;1]]` this compiles perfectly but returns an error saying that the match cases weren't complete, it seems that it is trying to mach `list<int>` with the cases and it isn't finding it. I expected that `list<obj>` would match lists of any type `'a` but thats not the case. **What pattern should I write to have it match a list of any type?** The function works perfectly for non-nested lists of objects.

Comment: I guess you will have to get some reflection going for these - may I ask why you want/need to do this - I usually try to not use these runtime-type checking

Comment: @Carsten I am writing a DSL for interop with Mathematica, this allows to pass a list of different types and nested lists to a Mathematica function. So that for example `Table [Power [n;2]; [n; 1; 10]]` would be legal syntax in F#

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169233/f-pattern-matching-matching-functions-lists-of-subtypes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140079/how-to-cast-an-object-to-a-list-of-generic-type-in-f.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way you can use pattern matching to check that an object is a value of a generic type with unspecified generic arguments. You can check whether it is `list<int>` or `list<obj>`, but it would have to be exactly this type - so `list<int>` won't be matched when you check for a type using `:? list<obj>` (also, you can write `:? list<_>`, but the compiler will just fill the `_` with `obj`)

If you only care about collections, you can however use the non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable` interface which all collections (lists, arrays, etc.) implement:

```
let rec list : (obj list -> Expr list) = function
    | head::tail -> 
        match head with
        | :? string as x'-> Symbol (x') :: list tail
        // Other cases you're already covering
        | :? float as x' -> Real x' :: list tail
        | :? Expr as x' -> x' :: list tail
        | :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as x' -> 
            // It is a collection and we can get its elements as `obj` values!
            let nested = x' |> Seq.cast |> List.ofSeq |> list
            List(nested) :: list tail
    | _ -> []
```

Comment: You can however write an active pattern that would compare the generic type definitions (using typedefof on one side and GetGenericTypeDefinition on the other).

Answer (score 2):

The pattern match is incomplete because `head` is of the type `obj`. Cases not covered are, for example `null`, `obj ()`, `1L` (64-bit integer), `System.Version ()`, `System.Guid("DAB51019-DF69-4547-BC3B-5CE06BE22A7B")`, `[| 1; 2 |]`, etc.

There are an unbounded number of cases not handled, because `obj` means *anything*, including custom types.

> What pattern should I write to have it match a list of any type?

You can always use the wildcard pattern `_`, but only you know what should happen in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have aleady tried using the wildcard pattern, I can use reflection to check that `x` is indeed a list (or array, or seq ... etc). but from that point I have `x : obj` and I don't know how type-cast this to `obj list` (so that I can pass it again to `list`)

Comment: @ZaidAjaj you cannot cast an `int list` to an `obj list`.  There is no inheritance relationship.  You could instantiate the list as an `obj list` by boxing the ints.  Instead of `[2; 1]` you would type `[box 2; box 1]`.