# Why is generic type in some expressions is matched as obj in F# pattern matching?

Tags: generics, f#, pattern-matching

I have the following code:

```
type Message<'a> = | Message of 'a

let handleMessage message =
    match box message with
    | :? Message<_> -> printfn "Message"
    | _ -> printfn "Not message"

let handleMessageEx message =
    match box message with
    | :? Message<int> -> printfn "Message"
    | _ -> printfn "Not message"

handleMessage <| Message 1
handleMessage <| Message (1 :> obj)
handleMessageEx <| Message 1
```

The output in F# Interactive is the following:

```
Not message
Message 
Message
```

Why does the first statement result in "Not message"? I.e. when matching a boxed value F# is not able to detect that it is of a generic type Message<_> and unless I specify the underlying type it sets it to object (therefore failing match on (Message 1)).

Comment: Can't explain well, so just a comment, but a generic type isn't really a type and so can't be the target of a pattern type test. Type test require a "concrete" type and so the wildcard is replaced by the most general thing possible `obj`. You could make the function itself generic `handleMessage<'a>` too but you need to put the generic parameter at call site to make it work `handleMessage<int> <| Message 1` (without you'll also get "Not message")

Comment: The problem is that obj is not the most general thing possible in F# world, because it won't match a concrete type. And I wonder why in case of Message<'a> F# doesn't leave 'a open, available for any matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see `_` as a type parameter, think of it as a fresh type parameter that you don't care about.  If we tweak your first definition accordingly:

```
let handleMessage message =
    match box message with
    | :? Message<'_a> -> printfn "Message"
    | _ -> printfn "Not message"
```

then the compiler gives us this helpful clue:

> warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable '_a has been constrained to be type 'obj'.

The problem is that the type parameter has to be given some *specific* value, but the compiler has no basis on which to pick one so it defaults to `obj`, which is not what you want.

There's no great way to do this out of the box, but you can create an active pattern to simplify the experience somewhat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140485/82959.

Comment: "The problem is that the type parameter has to be given some specific value, but the compiler has no basis on which to pick one so it defaults to obj, which is not what you want."

This is what I fail to understand. F# type inference doesn't usually work like this. If I define a function
let func (v : 'a) = printfn "%A" v
then 'a will not be given some specific value (obj), it will stay unbound because format specification "%A" doesn't bind to any type. Why is binding performed in other case?

Comment: And for the link to a workaround with active pattern - looks like I will need to do something like this.

Comment: @VagifAbilov because printfn "%A" doesn't care of the actual type given to it; it handles anything. On the opposite type testing puts a "constraint" to have a concrete type to test `Message<'a>` isn't a concrete type un less the function is also generic because at each use with a new generic argument (int, string, whatever) code for that specific type will be compiled on the fly where 'a will be replaced by that type effectively making the expected concrete type (`Message<int>` or `Message<string>)`

Comment: @Sehnsucht I see, it's getting clear. So the problem is with operator :? - it requires having a concrete type on the right side, so it binds 'a with obj unless anything specific is given. Makes sense although I wish this operator worked in a more loose way.

Comment: @VagifAbilov - I disagree with your framing of the `printfn` example.  At each call site of `func` the compiler knows the specific instantiation of `'a` at compile time, whereas here you expect the instantiation to vary at runtime.  This is a fundamental difference, and the CLR doesn't support any efficient technique for encoding the latter, so even if the compiler were modified to do what you expect the compiled code would need to use reflection to achieve it.

Comment: Agree. Of course the difference between compile time and runtime is principle.

Answer (score 4):

Simply speaking, `Message<_>` doesn't mean that you expect it to be generic, it means the compiler is free to infer the generic type argument to `Message`. Which, in absence of other constraints, results in making it `obj`. This also happens if you make the function generic - the generic type argument to the function (and, by extension, to `Message` type check) is decided at the call site:

```
let handleMessage<'a> (message: obj) =
    match message with
    | :? Message<'a> -> printfn "Message"
    | _ -> printfn "Not message"

handleMessage <| Message 1       // Not message -> 'a inferred to be obj
handleMessage<int> <| Message 1  // Message -> 'a inferred to be int
```

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
let handleMessage message =
    let typ = message.GetType()
    match typ with
    | _ when typ.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Message<_>> -> printfn "Message"
    | _ -> printfn "Not message"

handleMessage <| Message 1
handleMessage <| Message (1 :> obj)
```

Here instead of doing a type test you inspect the generic type definitions of both.

Comment: I could also write Message<'a> with the same result - 'a would be match as obj which become a problem because even though obj is root of all types, it doesn't match them in F# pattern matching.
Of course reflection can always offer a workaround, but I would like to leave this option as a last resort, partly because of its inefficiency, and this code is part of logging function which makes its performance critical.

Comment: Have you measured it? What this function does is pretty trivial, why would it be slow.

Comment: These particular reflection methods won't slow the things, but I simplified my case - I don't only want to match the message but also bind match result. The generic Message type in reality is a wrapper around a tuple, and I will need to extract those tuple values. All this using reflection.

Comment: Why not have the function handle `Message<obj>` then,  extract the argument and type match on that?

Comment: I will need to try on the actual (not simplified) definition. Perhaps it's not significant performance penalty. It's still sad though mixing F# pattern matching with reflection, but apparently there is no straightforward way.