# How to convert generic Discriminated Union to obj

Tags: f#

Given a DU like

```
type Result<'a, 'b> = Ok of 'a | Error of 'b
```

and some functions

```
let doA () = Ok true
let doB () = Error <| exn "Fail"
let doC = function | 1 -> Ok "one" | x -> Error x
```

How do you define a function to cast the value?

```
toObjResult : x:obj -> Result<obj, obj> //where x is guaranteed to be Result<'a,'b>
```

Usage

```
let data =
  [ doA() |> box
    doB() |> box
    docC 1 |> box
    docC 2 |> box ]
  |> List.map toObjResult
```

All attempts so far restrict the types of `'a` and `'b` to be `obj`

```
let toObjResult (x:obj) =
  match x with
  | :? Result<'a, 'b> as r ->
      match r with
      | Ok a -> Ok (box a)
      | Error b -> Error (box b)
  | _ -> Error <| (exn "Invalid type" |> box)
```

resulting in errors like

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Ok[System.Boolean,System.Object]' to type 'Result`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.
```

Comment: This answer to a question about matching generics may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39876212/59371

Comment: It seems undesirable to do this because it will replace compiler errors with runtime errors.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: There will be no runtime errors as the type is guaranteed to be `Result<'a, 'b>`. A number of functions are called via http and will each return `Result<_, _>`. If it is `Ok`, return a 200 with the value. If it is `Error`, return a 400 with the error message. The problem was how to get the corresponding `'a` and `'b` values. Pattern matching will not work because the types are unknown so a way to convert them to `obj` solves that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this without using reflection, enumerating all types, or modifying the type.

Using reflection can be slow, but lets you do what you want (see [the `GenericType` active pattern [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140079/how-to-cast-an-object-to-a-list-of-generic-type-in-f)) and the answer from @robkuz shows how you can do this by listing all the cases that you want to cover - the problem is that this does not scale well.

Finally, if you were happy to modify your `Result<'a, 'b>` type, you could add a non-generic interface that lets you get the value as a boxed value:

```
type IBoxedResult =
  abstract Boxed : Result<obj, obj>

and Result<'a, 'b> = 
  | Ok of 'a 
  | Error of 'b
  interface IBoxedResult with
    member x.Boxed =  
      match x with
      | Ok v -> Ok (box v)
      | Error v -> Error (box v)
```

Now you can cast `obj` to `IBoxedResult` and use `Boxed` to get the value as `Reslt<obj, obj>`:

```
[ box (Ok true)
  box (Ok 1) ]
|> List.map (fun o -> (o :?> IBoxedResult).Boxed)
```

Comment: Result was extended with `IBoxedResult`. Much simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have to match on the exact generic type params of your Result type in your matching expression

```
let matchR r = 
     match r with
     | Ok a -> Ok (box a)
     | Error b -> Error (box b)

 let toObjResult (x:obj) =
      match x with
      | :? Result<bool, _> as r -> matchR r
      | :? Result<string, int> as r -> matchR r
      | :? Result<_, Exception> as r -> matchR r
      | _ -> Error (box "Invalid type" )
```

sadly you can't match on unrealised type params (which is really bad)

Comment: Interesting I can't just match over unrealized type params. The only guarantee I have is that `b'` is an exception. For `a'`, it can be anything so it is no possible to pattern match over all values.