# F#, Deedle: Generic Frame constrained to type Frame< obj,obj >

Tags: .net, functional-programming, f#, deedle

I have a function that receives an obj and tries to guess if it’s a string, a Deedle Frame or something else:

```
let exampleF (data : obj) =
    match data with
    | :? string as s -> "string: " + s
    | :? Frame<'a,'b> as d -> "Frame"
    | _ -> "something else"
```

The problem is that Frame<’a,’b> is constrained to type Frame< obj,obj >. So if I had someFrame of type Frame< int,string >, exampleF would output “something else”. However, if exampleF had another branch with “ :? Frame< int,string > as d ->”, someFrame would be correctly caught.

How can I capture all Frames in a pattern matching like that without having to specify the inner types?

Comment: There has been some existing discussions on SO about this, see for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875110/why-is-generic-type-in-some-expressions-is-matched-as-obj-in-f-pattern-matching

Comment: Many thanks, Jim. I searched before asking the question, but it seems I was not fortunate in choosing the right search words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim Foye helped me to find the answer:

```
let exampleF data =
    match data.GetType() with
    | typ when typ.IsGenericType && typ.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Frame<_,_>> -> "Frame"
    | typ when typ = typeof<string> -> "string"
    | _ -> "something else"
```