# How cast a generic value:'T to an array<'R> on F#

Tags: json, reflection, f#, .net-core

I'm building reflection for a [JSON parser](https://github.com/xyncro/chiron), and hit a road when serializing arrays:

```
let rec toJson (value:'T) =
    let t = typedefof<'T>

    match t with
    | _ when FSharpType.IsRecord(t) ->
        let fields = fieldsOf<'T>
        let values = seq {
            for field in fields do
                let x = field.GetValue value

                let result = toField field x
                yield field.Name.ToLower(), result
        }               
        values |> Seq.filter(fun (_, x) -> x <> Null) |> List.ofSeq 
        |> Chiron.JsonObject.ofPropertyList 
        |> Chiron.JsonObject.toJson
        |> Chiron.Formatting.Json.format
    | _ when t.IsArray ->
        let te = t.GetElementType()

        let values = value :? seq<obj> <-- How turn value into a array/seq?
        let txt = value :?> IEnumerable |> Seq.map toJson |> String.concat ""
        txt
    | _ ->
        _toField t value
        |> Chiron.Formatting.Json.format

let rows:Log.LogSyncRow array = query...

rows |> toJson
```

The problem is `(value:'T)` is a record or a array of records, and can't see how enumerate them. I try with [How to cast an object to a list of generic type in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140079/how-to-cast-an-object-to-a-list-of-generic-type-in-f) but not work:

```
let values = value :?> seq<obj> 

Error FS0008: This runtime coercion or type test from type    'T     to     seq<obj>    involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed. (FS0008) (Server)
```

or

```
value :?> IEnumerable

Error FS0033: The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<_>' expects 1 type argument(s) but is given 0 (FS0033) (Server)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know what `'T` is, and so doesn't know whether `'T` is castable to `IEnumerable<obj>` at all. There are actually some types that can't be cast like this (which is what the compiler tells you: "*Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types*")

But you can still force the compiler to shut up about it - cast to an `obj` first, then cast to whatever you need:

```
value :> obj :?> seq<obj>
```

Or, alternatively, use the built-in function `box`, which is just the same cast to `obj`, only wrapped as a function:

```
box value :?> seq<obj>
```

Comment: Or use the built-in function `unbox` to do the same, as in `value |> unbox<seq<obj>>`.